# java LinkedList methods getFirst() and element()

Tags: java, linked-list

So I can see that from previous answers in stackoverflow that there is a difference  between `getFirst` and `peekFirst` as `peekFirst` won't throw an `exception` if the LinkedList is empty.

But what is the difference between `getFirst` and `element`?

> getFirst() Returns the first element in this list.
>
> element() Retrieves, but does not remove, the head (first element) of this list.

Both will throw out `NoSuchElementException` if empty.

Thanks!

Comment: *But what is the difference between getFirst and element?*  none. See -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, the implementation of `element` is

```
public E element() {
    return getFirst();
}
```

The javadoc even states

> This method is equivalent to {@link #getFirst()}

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 there is none. **But** Java is a hugely popular language, there are thousands of projects out there that use `element` and equally many that use `getFirst` so neither can be removed.

Comment: Ok. I guess I'll have to accept this. I always thought that there would be no completely identical/repeating implementation in any programming languages.

Comment: @luk2302 If you know something about the history of how two seemingly identical methods ended up in `LinkedList`, then you should add that to your answer.

Comment: @luk2302     If someone can show me the reason, I'll choose to accept that answer

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent as specified in the `Deque` docs.

> Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of the queue represented by this deque (in other words, the first element of this deque). This method differs from peek only in that it throws an exception if this deque is empty.
>
> This method is equivalent to getFirst().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#element()

Answer (score 2):

`element` is in the `Queue` interface, while `getFirst` is not.  But (as noted elsewhere) the behaviors are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The [source code for LinkedList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java) says it all:

```
public E element() {
    return getFirst();
}
```

The `element()` method just calls `getFirst()`.  So, in the case of the `LinkedList` implementation of `List`, both methods effectively do the same thing.

Note: The other implementation of the `Deque` interface, `ArrayDeque`, also has an `element()` implementation which just calls `getFirst()`.